# error running django example of python-openid

Tags: python, openid

I am newbie to django. I am running this example from https://github.com/openid/python-openid/tree/master/examples/djopenid

Any pointers to what I am doing wrong will be appreciated.

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /server/
Error importing template source loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.load_template_source: "'module' object has no attribute 'load_template_source'"
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:9001/server/
Django Version: 1.4
Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:    
Error importing template source loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.load_template_source: "'module' object has no attribute 'load_template_source'"
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py in find_template_loader, line 101
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.2
Python Path:    
['/home/murtaza/repos/python-openid/examples/djopenid',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.0.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipdb-0.7-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reimport-1.3dev_r77-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_openid-2.2.5-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode']
Server time:    Tue, 17 Jul 2012 09:12:55 -0500
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old example, it is probably not compatible with Django 1.4.

Comment: Oh yeah! Read the tutorial again:
"2. Install Django 0.95.1.
    If you find that the examples run on even newer versions of
    Django, please let us know!"